# Scroll-snap not working. I have looked up the existing questions and none of them helped

Tags: css

I am trying to implement scroll-snap effect. But there's a problem and I don't know what that is.
I have removed the redundant details so that we are left with the essence of the question.

Here is my html code:

```
<img src="1.JPG" class="stop">
<img src="1.JPG" class="stop">
<img src="1.JPG" class="stop">
<img src="1.JPG" class="stop">
<img src="1.JPG" class="stop">
<img src="1.JPG" class="stop">
<img src="1.JPG" class="stop">
<img src="1.JPG" class="stop">
<img src="1.JPG" class="stop">
<img src="1.JPG" class="stop">
```

And here is my css code:

```
body{
  scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
img{
  width: 50%;
}
stop{
  scroll-snap-stop: always;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two mistakes you made and there are some improvements needed in your CSS

1. Do not apply `scroll-snap-type` to the body tag, rather make a container and apply this property to the container.
2. `scroll-snap-align` does not work on the parent container, it works on a child only

Improvements:

1. Added `scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;` so, it will vertically snap the elements
2. Set `overflow-y: scroll` to make vertical scrolling possible
3. Also set max-height to the container.

So I tried it on codepen here's CSS:

```
.container {
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-height: 100vh
}

img {
    height: 100vh;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

Here's the working pen [link](https://codepen.io/prathameshkoshti/pen/eYNbbzJ?editors=1100)

I hope this clears your query.